# Sorting and writing files in python

Tags: python, sorting, text-files

I have text files that look like:

```
2.8     3.0   1
28.4    3.0   1
36.2    3.0   1
70.49   3.0   1
85.19   3.0   1
```

And I have the following code:

```
f = open('file.txt','r')

with open('file.txt') as fin:
    lines = f.readline()
print lines
with open ('file_1.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(lines)

with open ('file.txt') as fin:     
    lines = f.readlines()[0:]
print lines
with open ('file_2.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for el in lines:
        fout.write('{0}\n'.format(' '.join(el)))
f.close()
```

This outputs `file1` with the numbers in the first line. And then outputs `file2` with the list of remaining numbers. How can I get this to iterate over lines so the next file starts at line2 and so on? Essentially, iterating through all 40 lines and removing one line each time it outputs a file.

Put simply, I want it to output:

- file1=line1 only
- file2=lines 2 till 40

and then..

- file3= line2 only
- file4= lines1 and 3 till 40

..and so on

I'm new to python so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Format your code. What you posted here will not run at all. I can guess at what you meant, but I'd rather not. Please fix.

Comment: Why do you need to read the input in multiple times to do that? Just read it once, and write out in whatever combinations you want. Also, read about loops before attempting something like this.

Comment: Do not do `f = open('file.txt','r')` if you are going to do `with...`.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist. I'll edit those bits out. This code works fine for line1 and then the remaining lines. But I can't get it to start at line2? Any ideas?

Comment: Now might be a good time to select an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `with` context management and `readlines`/`writelines` to simplify I/O.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input:
    linebuf = input.readlines()
# The context manager will automatically close `input`
# no matter what happens (including errors)

for ind, line in enumerate(linebuf):
    with open('file.line_{}_only.txt'.format(ind + 1), 'w') as output:
        output.writelines([line])
    # Files named like "file.line_1_only.txt" will be closed here
    with open('file.lines_except_{}.txt'.format(ind + 1), 'w') as output:
        output.writelines(linebuf[:ind] + linebuf[ind + 1:])
    # Files named like "file.lines_except_1.txt" will be closed here
```

Comment: @AmnaAli. This is my code, not the other one. There are two answers. I believe that mine does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could find out how long the file is with len() and then use two for loops to iterate through and create a new text file every time.

```
# Ask how long the file is
with open("file.txt", "r+b") as text_file:
    lines = text_file.readlines() # returns a list of the lines in the file
num_lines = len(lines)

# Now use two for loops to iterate
for line in range(num_lines):
    new_filename = "file_"+str(line)+".txt"
    new_file = open(new_filename, "w")
    for item in lines[line:]:
        new_file.write("%s\n" % item)
    new_file.close()
```

This should produce a new file with a unique file name. Each file will contain one less row than the previous file.

Comment: Thanks @bobo! This looks like it would do what I need it to. But its crashing at    `line8 'for line in num_lines:`   saying 'int object is not iterable'. Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Replace `text_file = open("file.txt", "r+b")` with `with open("file.txt", "r+b") as text_file:`, indent the next two lines and get rid of `text_file.close()
`.

Comment: Also, `for line in num_lines` should be `for line in range(num_lines):`.

Comment: Made an edit for you. Please let me know if you approve

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist and @bobo! This iterates through each line and works well for the second file that I need, but for the first file- I need it to write out each line to a new file. So line1 is in a new file, line2 is in a new file and so on.. Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: @AmnaAli. That is exactly what my answer is doing. Have you tried running it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did run it; its writing out all the lines from 1 till 85, then 2 till 85 then 3 till 85 and so on. Which is perfect for the second file I need. But for the first, I need only line1, then line 2 and so on. Thanks very much!